# Debugging android app on a device remotely

Tags: android

Is it possible to install/debug applications using adb on a device that is connected to a remote machine.(IP address of the remote machine is known)?

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. If you found any solution, can you please share that with others?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your phone rooted you can use some apps like this http://www.appbrain.com/app/adb-over-wifi-widget/bohlool.net.wifiadb