# Android - Is there is a way to remotely open and debug a given Android device?

Tags: android, remote-debugging

My scenario is as follow:
I'm working with an app development which a bug occurs in the app when it is in a different country than mine, and only there. The bug is related with a fail in an image download through an URL access. Right now, I haven't figured out yet what it can be. Some subjects I've already looked up are:

- Its not related to internationalization and/or culture, because the code does not implement this;
- Its not related to firewall/security access, because if the user in the other country opens the image's URL, he can look at the image;

Without rooting the device, is there is a way to remotely open and debug a given Android device, just like a [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or a [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)?

Similar questions are:

- [Debugging android app on a device remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508649/debugging-android-app-on-a-device-remotely)
- [Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625528/remote-debugging)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754162/remote-debugging-with-android-emulator

Comment: This can be of help... :)

Comment: @mthama Did you find any way to achieve this?

Comment: Not exactly remote debugger but you could add [Bugfender](https://bugfender.com/) to your project and create a new issue when this bug happens.
It won't be real time but at least you can get a good perspective of what's happening

Answer (score 7):

Well,
you can debug a device using a TCP/IP connection (I sometimes debug using WIFI at home). all you need to do is make sure the remote device is connected to the internet and is accessible to your PC with a direct TCP/IP connection.

As the Android device is connected in another location - you'll have to make sure your router's firewall allows outgoing connection for communications in the port ADB is using , and that the target Android device receives communications in that port (if it's behind a router - the router should allow connections under the righ port and forward all comm in that port to the android device).

in other words - you have to "tunnel" your communication to the target device. there are other tunneling solutions/products but I've never used them and I prefer the "manual" way

Good luck,
Dan

EDIT : in Android 11 - adb can work on WIFI natively : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#wireless

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can have the user install something like aLogcat and have them send you a log with the failure.

Comment: Hi unexpected62. Thank for the answer.
Its a good solution, but not my desired approach... I'm looking for something more "real-time".

Comment: Yea I hear you. Just wasn't sure if you knew apps like that existed.

Answer (score 2):

Well as remotely debugging a device I don't know but you can use [ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android)](https://code.google.com/p/acra/) .

All you need is to set up a google doc, add the lib to your project and when the app crashes it will send a crash report to that google doc. [See quick setup here](http://acra.ch/)

Comment: Hi pepipe, thanks for the answer as well. The app don't crash. It just can't retrieve a given image from the web for an (yet) unknown reason. I think it is comming as null. I want a remote debug to check what are the methods returned values. Strange is that here, in my country, the app just works fine... o_O

Comment: Well if want to be sure make something with the image if is null it will crash and then you'll be sure :p